# vim: Execute BundleInstall without showing the vim interface

Tags: vim, scripting

I have a installation script that I use to initalize my vim plugins when I'm on a new machine

```
#!/bin/bash

# Clone vundle into the directory if it's not already
if [[ ! -e bundle/vundle/.git ]]
then
    mkdir -p bundle
    rm -rf bundle/vundle
    git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git bundle/vundle
fi

vim +BundleInstall +qall
```

However, this brings up vim. I was curious if there was a way to have vim hide its interface but still execute the BundleInstall script?

In other words the script would hang until the BundleInstall command finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was actually embarrassingly simple, not sure why I didn't try this in the first place.

```
vim +BundleInstall +qall 2&> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim is an interactive editor; the best you can try is *silent batch* mode:

```
vim -es <<<BundleInstall
```

See `:help -s-ex` for details.